# Socket.io pm2 reload duplicates sockets

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, pm2

I am running node.js in cluster mode with socket.io and pm2 now like this (default socket.io chat "hello world" example)

```
var
    probe = require('pmx').probe(),
    app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),

    port = 3131 + parseInt(process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE),
    counter = probe.counter({
        name: 'User online'
    });



io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    counter.inc();
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        counter.dec();
    });

    socket.on('message', function() {
        socket.emit('message', port);
    });
});

server.listen(port, function() {});
```

and default html client (all who visits my page, executes this)

```
var socket;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/', {
        'reconnection': true,
        'reconnectionDelay': 500,
        'reconnectionAttempts': 3
    });

    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        socket.emit('message', {});
    }, 2000);
});
```

this goes with default nginx sticky sessions configuration (http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/ found here, one difference, i skipped last redis part, only nginx config is used)

```
upstream io_nodes {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0 .0 .1: 3131;
    server 127.0 .0 .1: 3132;
    server 127.0 .0 .1: 3133;
    server 127.0 .0 .1: 3134;
    server 127.0 .0 .1: 3135;
    server 127.0 .0 .1: 3136;
    server 127.0 .0 .1: 3137;
    server 127.0 .0 .1: 3138;
}
```

and pm2 config like this:

```
{
    "apps": [{
        "name": "server",
        "script": "server.js",
        "instances": 8,
        "exec_mode": "cluster",
        "max_memory_restart": "2G"
    }]
}
```

And i have several problems:

1. First is user online count is highter when whole my project online users count, for example (real case!) if i have 3800 users online, my keymetrics (or simple io.eio.clientsCount) shows 4000 or even 5000 total clients connected.
2. Follows from the first, if i use pm2 reload or pm2 restart, i have case   when first node duplicates or even multiplies several times sockets count, and gets 100%+ cpu load. Sometimes all nodes, not only first multiplies sockets count. To avoid this i need to kill pm2, wait a minute, and when start again.

Situation after pm2 reload (in real there is only 3868 users online):

[image: in real there is only 3868 users online]

Comment: For your first issue, `socket.io` makes request more than one time to the server. Because of this, `Keymetrics` may show more count than expected. I recommend sharing this issue with them. I wonder the solution of your second problem too.

Comment: Possible solution (idea of) https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2508#issuecomment-259962370

Answer (score 0):

if you do not mind use only one process to handle ws,
you can do this:

```
let clusterId = process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE
if (clusterId > 0) return app
//otherwise, do atttch the ws server
```

Comment: Thank you, already solved with authentication via JWT, now everything is fine :)

Comment: @MyMomSaysIamSpecial if you already solved your problem answering your own question and marking it as the correct answer would benefit everyone